# how to merge find difference array and array json javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, object

Anyone can help me with merge difference two **array** and **array json**. You can check my below code and result that I want to check difference between **arr** and **arr2**

First Array

```
let arr=[ '124', '125', '126', '127' ]
```

Second Array

```
let arr2=[{ 
            _id: '125',
            itemId: '125',
            onHand: 10,
            inventoryValue: 70,
            avgCost: 7 
          },
          { 
            _id: '124', 
            itemId: '124', 
            onHand: 10,
            inventoryValue: 50,
            avgCost: 5 
          } 
         ]
```

I want result like that

```
let arr3=['126', '127' ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `filter` your `arr` based on whether `arr2` does not include each value as an `_id` by using `some`:

```js
let arr = ['124', '125', '126', '127']

let arr2 = [{
    _id: '125',
    itemId: '125',
    onHand: 10,
    inventoryValue: 70,
    avgCost: 7
  },
  {
    _id: '124',
    itemId: '124',
    onHand: 10,
    inventoryValue: 50,
    avgCost: 5
  }
];

let arr3 = arr.filter(e => !arr2.some(({ _id }) => _id == e));

console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: Whoops - sorry @B001ᛦ, fixed now.

Comment: It doesn't @sreypick - I fixed it.

Comment: No problem whatsoever @sreypick - if my answer fixed your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the grey tick mark to the left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Find the index of all the ids od arr2 in arr1 and splice them form arr1

```js
let arr = ['124', '125', '126', '127'];

let arr2 = [{
    _id: '125',
    itemId: '125',
    onHand: 10,
    inventoryValue: 70,
    avgCost: 7
  },
  {
    _id: '124',
    itemId: '124',
    onHand: 10,
    inventoryValue: 50,
    avgCost: 5
  }
];
arr2.forEach(function(element) {
      var index = arr.indexOf(element._id);
      if (index > -1) {
        arr.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
    console.log(arr);
```